# wicd tray panel icon (14.04, unity)

Tags: panel, wicd

i recently switched to wicd and I'm really happy with it.
But unfortunately it loads no panel icon.

Anything I can do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I liked wicd for it's stability as well, but it appears that the project is not being developed further - the last update to wicd was back on 2012-04-30 (in the Ubuntu 12.04 days) and it has not seen updates since, although the source code is available if you wanted to tackle the project.

You've probably loaded wicd to try to solve a connectivity issue - perhaps solving the base issue would be a better tactic.